# La préposition "de" et les adverbes de quantité

Tags: prépositions, adverbes

J'ai lu que la préposition *de* est utilisée lorsqu'on veut dire une quantité de quelque chose. Alors j'ai un doute, les adverbes de quantité doivent-ils être suivis de la préposition *de* de la même manière que les expressions de quantité ; comme « un verre », « un tas », « un morceau » etc.

Par exemple comment dirait-on en français "there's enough food" ?

> Il y a assez de nourriture.

ou

> Il y a assez nourriture.

Même chose avec des adverbes comme *plutôt, moins, beaucoup* etc.

Comment: Si l'on veut dire par example en anglais: "there's enough food", comment serait la manière correcte pour en dire en français ? "Il y a assez de nourriture" ou "il y a assez nourriture"? Même cas avec les adverbes comme plutôt, moins, beaucoup, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En français, il y a presque toujours un article devant un nom commun, contrairement à l’anglais. On dit donc : il y a assez de nourriture.

Les mots “avec”, “plutôt” et “en” peuvent être suivis de noms sans article comme dans l’expression “avec pertes et fracas”.

En revanche, il y a toujours un article devant un nom qui suit “beaucoup” ou “moins”

Comment: *Toujours* est exagéré...

Comment: @jlliagre corrigé